# Finding HTML tags in string

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match

I know this question is around SO, but I can't find the right one and I still suck in Regex :/

I have an `string` and that string is valid HTML. Now I want to find all the tags with an certain `name` and `attribute`.

I tried this regex (i.e. div with type): `/(<div type="my_special_type" src="(.*?)<\/div>)/`.

Example string:

```
<div>Do not match me</div>
<div type="special_type" src="bla"> match me</div>
<a>not me</a>
<div src="blaw" type="special_type" > match me too</div>
```

If I use preg_match then I only get `<div type="special_type" src="bla"> match me</div>` what is logical because the other one has the attributes in a different order.

What regex do I need to get the following `array` when using `preg_match` on the example string?:

```
array(0 => '<div type="special_type" src="bla"> match me</div>',
      1 => '<div src="blaw" type="special_type" > match me too</div>')
```

Comment: if it is a valid HTML can't you use [PHP DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)? i don't recommend using `preg_*` for HTML

Comment: PHP parse DOM:
how to:
DOM-Methoden/wiki/PHP/Tutorials/DOMDocument:
https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/PHP/Tutorials/DOMDocument

https://codingreflections.com/php-parse-html/ 
We will do the following jobs with our sample HTML:

Select element by Id
Get elements by its tag name
Find elements by class
Find all links in a page
Inserting HTML element
Deleting an element
Dealing with attributes

https://codingreflections.com/php-parse-html/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A general advice: **Dont use regex to parse HTML** It will get messy if the HTML changes..

Use `DOMDocument` instead:

```
$str = <<<EOF
<div>Do not match me</div>
<div type="special_type" src="bla"> match me</div>
<a>not me</a>
<div src="blaw" type="special_type" > match me too</div>
EOF;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($str);    
$selector = new DOMXPath($doc);

$result = $selector->query('//div[@type="special_type"]');

// loop through all found items
foreach($result as $node) {
    echo $node->getAttribute('src');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I accepted the other question because that one looped through the found nodes.

Comment: @Sven Know that looping in PHP is slow. Using `XPath` is definitely they way to go here - especially if the HTML is larger than shown in question. test it

Comment: Can you give me an example how to loop through the found items from `$result`? Because I can't find an method like `items()` or something and i have multiple tags in the html that i want to find.

Comment: @Sven OHHH. this means I've ruined another post of mine O: (edited the wrong answer accidently) ...

Comment: @Sven No problem! :) I'm happy that you've finally accepted the XPath solution. Not because of the 15 reps I got, it's because XPath is the way to go here. If you get fluent with XPath you'll see that you can select everything that comes in mind - and more! ;) But there are also situations where XPath has disadvantages (from performance sight of things) that's especially if you select by node name or id attr.. in this cases pure DOM would perform better

Comment: doesn't work with meta tag especially with `http-equiv`

Answer (score 5):

As hek2msql said, you better use DOMDocument

```
$html = '
<div>Do not match me</div>
<div type="special_type" src="bla"> match me</div>
<a>not me</a>
<div src="blaw" type="special_type" > match me too</div>';

$matches = get_matched($html);


function get_matched($html){
    $matched = array();

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHtml($html);

    $length = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div')->length;

    for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){
        $type = $dom->getElementsByTagName("div")->item($i)->getAttribute("type");

        if($type != 'special_type')
            continue;

        $matched[] = $dom->getElementsByTagName("div")->item($i)->getAttribute('src');
    // or   $matched[] = $dom->getElementsByTagName("div")->item($i)->nodeValue;

    }

    return $matched;

}
```

Comment: That's bollocks. You really suggest to iterate over nodes instead of using XPATH?? Seems that you don't understood what hek2mgl said

Comment: i never said "instead of using XPATH" ofcourse he could use XPATH.

Comment: If the hmtl is like this _$html = '
<div>Do not <strong>match</strong> me</div>_ then it remove the strong tag.