# How can I detect a html tag on a string with php?

Tags: php, html, yii2

I need to know what tag html there is a string, for example:

```
$string = '<a href="http://example.com/">Hello World!</a>'
$result= 'a';
```

Is there function in PHP?

Comment: Do you need to know *when* a tag is present in a string, or *removing* it from a string?

Comment: I need to know what the tag is present (sorry for my english)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use preg_match :

```
 $result = preg_match("/<[^<]+>/",$string, $res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DOMDocument (http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to build a DOM from an HTML string and then loop through each element individually to find the tags.

See this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/18800862/3002418) for an example.