# how to print specific tag using curl

Tags: php, curl, domdocument

how to print text from `<p>` tag using `curl` and `DOMDocument` i try like this but not showing anything.

```
<?php

$url = "http://www.blablabla.org/dorama/201105455/kimi-wa-petto";
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$dom = new DOMDocument();

@$dom->loadHTML($html);

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('p') as $link) {
        echo $link->getAttribute('p');
        echo "<br />";
}
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding HTML tags in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800807/finding-html-tags-in-string)

Comment: Do you know what getAttribute does? So your looking for the value of `<p p="value"></p>`, I think your after `$link->nodeValue`, but i've been wrong before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to print out the text inside the `<p>` tags, the use `$textContent`...

```
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('p') as $link) {
        echo $link->textContent;
        echo "<br />";
}
```

If you want the whole XML, you can output it using `saveXML()` with the node as the point to output from ...

```
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('p') as $link) {
        echo $dom->saveXML( $link);
        echo "<br />";
}
```

As this is HTML, you may want to replace the `saveXML()` call with `saveHTML()`.

Comment: if you're running it in the command line, sure, that is sufficient. but if you're printing it to a web browser, you'll need `echo htmlentities($link->textContent,ENT_QUOTES|ENT_SUBSTITUTE|ENT_DISALLOWED|ENT_HTML5,'UTF-8',true);` , your code has a xss javascript injection vulnerability. htmlentities would protect you. to test this yourself, run it on a page containing `<p>&lt;script&gt;alert&lpar;&quot;vulnerable&excl;&quot;&rpar;&semi;&lt;&sol;script&gt;</p>`

Comment: @hanshenrik depends on what the purpose of the output is.  As I don't know what the content is and the purpose of this code, it could be that they want all of the markup to be included.  But useful point for OP to consider.

Comment: if you wanted the markup, you wouldn't be using textContent, you would be using $domd->saveHTML(node) - or if you wanted it saved in a db, you wouldn't use echo.

Comment: using `saveXML` give me more then what i want to do. perfect.
can u answer my next question @NigelRen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48250675/how-to-print-only-one-tag-with-curl