# how to print only one tag with curl

Tags: php, curl, domdocument

i have 2 or 3 tag `<p>` in my web but, im just want to print first and second `<p>`.

how i can do that?

here my code

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.web.org/dorama/1401143633/momikeshite-fuyu--wagaya-no-mondai-nakatta-koto-ni";
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('p') as $link) {
        echo $dom->saveXML( $link);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `getElementsByTagName()` you get a list of nodes ( DOMNodeList ) which you currently use `foreach()` to iterate over all of them.  If you just want the first, you can use `item()` to fetch the particular one you want (0 in this case)...

```
echo $dom->saveXML( $dom->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0) );
```

Comment: sorry, im edit my question. i want to show `p` first and second.
cause `p` first is image `p` second is synopsis

Comment: If you want to show the second one, replace (0) with (1).

Comment: Yes - so you use the line above for the first one and then do another echo with the same line but replace the (0) with (1) for the main content.

Comment: You can use preg_replace with the result of `saveXML()` but not with any of the DOM elements.  You would use something like XPath with DOM to find specific nodes and remove them.