# strip html title tags and its content - in php

Tags: php, html, tags, strip-tags

Is there a way to strip all the h1 h2, h3... tags with its content?
I need to get a cleaned text for one task.

The other task is to get just the first h2-content without the html-tags.

This is my original copy:

```
<h2>Title of product</h2> </h3>Subtitle of product</h3> 
Here starts the first paragraph and goes on to the next... 
<h3>Subtitle of the paragraph</h3> Here goes on the second paragraph.
```

Task 1: Get just the copy text without any html tag and any of its content, just like this:

```
Here starts the first paragraph and goes on to the next... 
Here goes on the second paragraph.
```

Task 2: Get just the content of the first h2-tag and nothing more, just like this:

```
Title of product
```

Hope you can help me. I have no clue how to do this in php.
I know you can strip but I do not know how to cut out (Task 2) a specific sequence.

My attempt for task 1 is this:

```
$copy = trim(preg_replace('/\t+/', '', htmlspecialchars($article->getCopy())))
```

It fails to cut away the content within the html tags.

Comment: Did you search before ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253027/get-everything-between-tag-and-tag-with-php

Comment: Use this approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800807/finding-html-tags-in-string